# Lines drawn in pygame but are not displayed

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I'm trying to program a simple financing program and still designing the UI. However, I ran into some issues.

```py
def stockdisplay(asset, turn):
    win.fill(dblue)
    stockA = pygame.Rect(0, 160, 250, 170)
    stockB = pygame.Rect(250, 160, 250, 170)
    stockC = pygame.Rect(0, 330, 250, 170)
    leave = pygame.Rect(250, 330, 250, 170)
    loadImage("../Images/stock.png", (245, 150), (200, 300))
    WriteLine("S    T", white, bigFont, (110, 75))
    WriteLine("C    K", white, bigFont, (410, 75))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, (0, 160), (500, 160))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, (250, 160), (250, 500))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, (0, 330), (500, 330))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE) or (event.type == pygame.QUIT): exit() #Escape Mechanism
            if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1):
                if stockA.collidepoint(event.pos): print("Stock A")
                elif stockB.collidepoint(event.pos): print("Stock B")
                elif stockC.collidepoint(event.pos): print("Stock C")
                elif leave.collidepint(event.pos): main(asset, turn)
def WriteLine(text, colour, font, pos):
    text2 = font.render(text, True, colour)
    textRect = text2.get_rect()
    textRect.center = pos
    win.blit(text2, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()
def loadImage(src, pos, scale):
    img = pygame.image.load(src)
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, scale)
    imgRect = img.get_rect()
    imgRect.center = pos
    win.blit(img, imgRect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

These are the functions I wrote to display the UI. However, whenever I run the program, the lines that were supposed to be drawn by the `pygame.draw.line()` is simply not there. The rectangles are still in the programs as they still respond to clicks.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One call of `pygame.display.update()` is sufficient, but it needs to be done after all the drawing. Remove `pygame.display.update()` from `WriteLine` and `loadImage`, but do a single `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the application loop:

```py
def stockdisplay(asset, turn):
    win.fill(dblue)
    stockA = pygame.Rect(0, 160, 250, 170)
    stockB = pygame.Rect(250, 160, 250, 170)
    stockC = pygame.Rect(0, 330, 250, 170)
    leave = pygame.Rect(250, 330, 250, 170)
    loadImage("../Images/stock.png", (245, 150), (200, 300))
    WriteLine("S    T", white, bigFont, (110, 75))
    WriteLine("C    K", white, bigFont, (410, 75))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, (0, 160), (500, 160))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, (250, 160), (250, 500))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, (0, 330), (500, 330))
    
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE) or (event.type == pygame.QUIT): exit() #Escape Mechanism
            if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1):
                if stockA.collidepoint(event.pos): print("Stock A")
                elif stockB.collidepoint(event.pos): print("Stock B")
                elif stockC.collidepoint(event.pos): print("Stock C")
                elif leave.collidepint(event.pos): main(asset, turn)

        pygame.display.update() # <-- INSERT

def WriteLine(text, colour, font, pos):
    text2 = font.render(text, True, colour)
    textRect = text2.get_rect()
    textRect.center = pos
    win.blit(text2, textRect)
    # pygame.display.update() <-- DELETE

def loadImage(src, pos, scale):
    img = pygame.image.load(src)
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, scale)
    imgRect = img.get_rect()
    imgRect.center = pos
    win.blit(img, imgRect)
    # pygame.display.update() <-- DELETE
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)